# How to get status response in stats

Tags: php, statistics

I want to get status response in my stats, so that if any page link is broken or something i get to know it, I know to get status response I can use

```
$status = http_response_code ();
```

and then store the `$status` response in database.

this can give me the status response for `200 Connect ok(and similar)`, as the page requested is linked with stats file.

but the problem is if there is `404 NOT Found(and similar)` error then I will not get any status stats by this method, as the error page is is not linked with stats file.

So my question is how to get that type of error, can any body suggest me the right way or tutorial to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think it'll be best if you parse your webserver/reverse proxy logs to get that type of information. for instance with a bit of tweaking apache can [log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) not just source ip / requested url / response code but also time of handling a query or cookies.